# Windows 8 disk usage 100% at start up

Tags: windows-8

I have researched this problem but none of the answers work. The high disk usage starts when I power on the computer and it stays at 100% for about 30 seconds, then goes right down to around 2% and doesn't happen again. Another strange thing is, this only happens on two of the 3 users on this computer. When I open up task manager, it shows that this happens for about 30 seconds and then never happens again. Also, (I am not sure if this is relevant) my AMD driver also stops responding during this and goes back to normal after the 30 second period. I have an intel core i5, 12GB ram,7200 rpm hard drive and AMD radeon hd 7750.

Comment: what are you using to determine that there is 100% disk usage?

Comment: This is pretty normal if you have a lot of programs running on startup.

Comment: capture a boot trace with xbootmgr: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE Let the countdown tick to 0. this captures 120 seconds after boot and should include the disk IO. Share the COMPRESSED ETL file

Comment: Have you captured the boot trace?

Answer (score 0):

I will go out on a limb here and guess that you have a PC with a low cost HDD. Maybe even a laptop with a 2.5" 5400 rpm laptop drive.

So reaching what Windows 8 believes to be 100% disk utilisation is really easy and you will find it happening pretty often. I have an HP gaming laptop that my son now uses with an i5 processor, 6GB RAM for example that has a 2.5" 5400 rpm drive and it spends 1/2 its life at 100%.

---

UPDATE: `MsMpEng.exe` is Microsoft Security Essentials. I'd expect that to maybe generate high CPU as it does sometimes. It could generate a fair bit of disk utilisation too.

`DellDataVault.exe` is part of Dell's Support Assistant. It runs as a service and I can't find any details as to what it actually provides but it looks like many people are having problems with it. You can try delaying the start of the service or you can uninstall the support assistant. As this is data related, you could imagine that it might hit the disk fairly hard at startup?

Comment: My computer is a inspiron 660 with  12 GB ram, 7200 rpm hard drive, AMD Radeon HD 7750,windows 8.1.

Comment: :} Can't win 'em all! Can I suggest then using Windows Performance Monitor to record what is actually using the drive?

Comment: Well, in task manager, in the "details" part, it shows that MsMpEng.exe makes the most I/O reads, DellDataVault.exe, the most I/O writes and system, the most I/O bytes written, does this help?